# using rtk query, how to pull this data from another view

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

I am trying to understand functionality with Redux toolkit and RTK Query.
I have a functioning query in one view.  My question is how do I pull this information in another view?

this is how I launch the query in view #1

```
const Sidebar = () => {
const { data: clients = [], isFetching: clientsFetching } =
useGetClientsQuery("x@x.com");
```

this is my single api slice object

```
//define our single api slice object
export const tradesApi = createApi({
//the cache reducer expects to be added at 'state.api' (already default - this is optional)
reducerPath: "tradesApi",
//all of our requests will have urls starting with '/fakeApi'
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://localhost:44304/api/" }),
//the 'endpoints' represent operations and requests for this server
endpoints: (builder) => ({
//the 'getposts' endpoint is a "query" operation that returns data
getClients: builder.query<ClientData[], string>({
  query: (username) => `/dashboard/returnClients?username=${username}`,
}),
getTradeDetail: builder.query<TradeData, number>({
  query: (id) => `/dashboard/returnTest?id=${id}`,
}),
}),
});

export const { useGetTradesQuery, useGetClientsQuery, useGetTradeDetailQuery } =
 tradesApi;
```

when I am in view #2, how do I pull this information without querying the api again?  I simply want to grab it from the store.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call `useGetClientsQuery("x@x.com");` in the other component. It won't make another request, but just pull the data from the store.

Comment: sorry for the dumb question but what would be the difference in code if I want to pull the stored data vs actually make another call to database?

Comment: You would use `refetchOnMount`. But generally: queries are there for getting data on the server. That data usually stays "the same" for quite a while, and you want it "the same" throughout your application. If it updates in one place, it should update everywhere.
If you want to send something to the server to make a change there, that would be done with a mutation

Comment: I have two use cases.  1.  the data will stay "the same" for quite a while.  BUT 2.  with a different request, the data will be changing constantly in the database, so I'll want to keep calling about every minute.  so are you saying I will call refetchOnMount every minute?

Comment: You can use `pollingInterval` for regular checking from the server. Or you have that different request `invalidate` a tag `provided` by your query and have it refetch because of that.